# Question about proof of Countable subadditivity of Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying real analysis from the Terence Tao book. In Exercise 1.2.3. (iii) they ask the reader to prove subadditivity of Lebesgue outer measure. It mentions the proof should use the axiom of choice, Tonelli's theorem for series, and $\epsilon/2^n$ trick.

The proof I came up with used only tonelli's theorem, and seemed almost immediate. So there's probably something wrong with it...

Given $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$

$$m^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = \inf \sum_{n=1}^\infty |B_n| $$

over all covers of  $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ by a countable set of boxes $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

Given any cover of each of individual sets $E_n$ by a sequence of boxes $\{B_{n,m}\}_{m=1}^\infty$, we have  $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subseteq \cup_{n,m=1}^\infty B_{n,m}$ making it a cover included in the infimum above.

Therefore
$$ 
\inf \sum_{n=1}^\infty |B_n| \le \inf \sum_{n,m=1}^\infty |B_{n,m}| = \inf \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty |B_{n,m}| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(E_n)
$$

The inequality is due to the right side infimum being over the same function but over a set contained in the one considered by the left side infimum.

The first equality is due to Tonelli's theorem for series.

The second equality is direct from the definition of $m^*$.

Comment: I may have figured out why they mention the epsilon/2**n trick... the second equality is not obvious because the infimum is outside the outer sum, but using the trick we can show we can select B(n,m)'s, for each n, to within epsilon/2**n of m*(En), so the infimum is no more than the sum of m*'s, plus epsilon (for any epsilon>0) and that is why they are equal

Comment: still no idea where the axiom of choice should be used, tho

Comment: (A note for possible future readers:) As explicitly stated in the Xiao's answer below, you _choose_ "any cover of each of individual sets" $E_n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that in your argument $m^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = \inf\sum_{n=1}^\infty |B_n|$, the index isn't very clear.

To show $m^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(E_n)$, it suffices to show that $m^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(E_n) + \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $\epsilon$ be given, for each $E_n$, define $\mathcal F_n$ to be the collection of countable collection of boxes (which means $\{B_{n,k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{F}_n$) such that

1. $E_n \subset \cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} B_{n,k}$,
2. $m^*(E_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} \geq \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} |B_{n,k}|$.

By Axiom of Choice, we take one $\{B_{n,k}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ from each $\mathcal F_n$, we see that by construction $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \subset \cup_{(n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2} B_{n,k}$, then
\begin{align}
m^*(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) &\leq m^*(\cup_{(n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2} B_{n,k})\\
&\leq \sum_{(n,k) \in \mathbb{N}^2} |B_{n,k}|\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |B_{n,k}|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (m^*(E_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} )\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(E_n) + \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Let me ask you one question, please? You stated that $m^*(\cup_{(n,k)\in \mathbb{N}^2}B_{n,k})\leq \sum_{(n,k)\in \mathbb{N}^2}|B_{n,k}|$. How did you get this inequality? I know that this is true if we have union depending on one variable but in our case it depends on two variables $n,k$. Could you give more details about this, please?

Comment: @ZFR We can rewrite the union as $\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k=1}^\infty B_{n,k}$. And this is just a countable union. Or more precisely, we can find a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$, so union over $\mathbb{N}^2$ can be rewritten as a union over $\mathbb{N}$ (a single variable).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain why $\sum \limits_{(n,k)\in \mathbb{N}^2}|B_{n,k}|=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|B_{n,k}|$? And what is the definition of $\sum \limits_{(n,k)\in \mathbb{N}^2}|B_{n,k}|$?

Comment: @ZFR if we are summing over non-negative values, i.e. the $|B_{n,k}|$'s here, the order of the summation between $n$ and $k$ doesn't matter. This is because of the Fubini's theorem for non-negative functions.